# How to count the values in a tibble or data frame to produce a new output table?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, tibble

I have the following code:

```
gm <- c("Alex", "Ashton", "Brett", "Chris", "Dave", "Ian", "Jack", "Jon", "Katz", "Mikulich", "Nate", "Todd")

year <- (2012:2019)

# podium placement, by year
first <- c("Mikulich", "Nate", "Nate", "Chris", "Nate", "Nate", "Dave", "Dave")
second <- c("Jon", "Alex", "Ian", "Todd", "Jon", "Chris", "Jon", "Jon")
third <- c("Katz", "Katz", "Jack", "Dave", "Katz", "Katz", "Chris", "Todd")

podium <- tibble(year, first, second, third)
```

producing the following tibble, `podium`:

```
year    first       second    third
<int>   <chr>       <chr>     <chr>

2012    Mikulich    Jon       Katz  
2013    Nate        Alex      Katz  
2014    Nate        Ian       Jack  
2015    Chris       Ross      Dave  
2016    Nate        Jon       Katz  
2017    Nate        Chris     Katz  
2018    Dave        Jon       Chris 
2019    Dave        Jon       Ross
```

I would like to have a tibble or data frame (12x4) that lists each GM and counts the number of top 3 finishes into an output that looks something like this:

```
GM         first    second    third
<chr>      <int>    <int>     <int>

Alex       0        1         0
Ashton     0        0         0
Brett      0        0         0
Chris      1        1         1
Dave       2        0         1
Ian        0        1         0
Jack       0        0         1
Jon        0        4         0
Katz       0        0         4
Mikulich   1        0         0
Nate       4        0         0
Todd       0        1         1
```

I can use `podium %>% count(first)` to get an individual distribution, but I'm wondering if there a more efficient way to create the entire table.

`podium %>% count(first)`:

```
first      n
<chr>      <int>

Chris      1
Dave       2
Mikulich   1
Nate       4
```

Comment: Can you please check `length(unique(unlist(podium[-1])))#
[1] 10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `pivot_longer` to reshape to 'long' format, then do the `count` and reshape it back to 'wide'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
podium %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -year, values_to = 'GM') %>%
    count(name, GM) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0))
# A tibble: 10 x 4
#   GM       first second third
#   <chr>    <int>  <int> <int>
# 1 Chris        1      1     1
# 2 Dave         2      0     1
# 3 Mikulich     1      0     0
# 4 Nate         4      0     0
# 5 Alex         0      1     0
# 6 Ian          0      1     0
# 7 Jon          0      4     0
# 8 Todd         0      1     1
# 9 Jack         0      0     1
#10 Katz         0      0     4
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a huge help! The only thing missing is that it doesn't include the GMs who never placed in the top 3. I hope I don't have to recreate an entirely new set of data.

Comment: @ACH From the data showed, I get only 10 unique elements i.e. `podium %>%
     pivot_longer(cols = -year, values_to = 'GM') %>% distinct(GM) %>% nrow#
[1] 10`